# Evaluation of the derivative of some vector r

Tags: calculus, vectors

Just a quick and simple explanation as the evaluation of the following (annoyed I can't find the evaluation of this online):

Defining:

$$
\frac{\partial{\vec{r}}}{\partial{R}}=\sin\theta\cos\phi\mathbf{i}+\sin\theta\sin\phi\mathbf{j}+\cos\theta\mathbf{k}
$$

How would I evaluate:

$$
\left|\left|{\frac{\partial{\vec{r}}}{\partial{R}}}\right|\right|
$$

(That is to say I have $\vec{r}=R\sin\theta\cos\phi\mathbf{i}+R\sin\theta\sin\phi\mathbf{j}+R\cos\theta\mathbf{k}$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\left|\frac{\partial{\vec{r}}}{\partial{R}}\right|=\sqrt{(\sin\theta\cos\phi)^2+(\sin\theta\sin\phi)^2+(\cos\theta)^2} = \sqrt{(\sin\theta)^2[(\cos\phi)^2+(\sin\phi)^2]+(\cos\theta)^2} = \sqrt{(\sin\theta)^2+(\cos\theta)^2} = 1
$$ I think this is what you wanted to know. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think so. But could you expand that a little, show me how you got to this...and show each step by step. I should be able to accept the answer when I am happy I have understood these stages...

Comment: There is no such steps.It is actually a definition.Magnitude of a vector is defined in this way.You just square the coefficients of $\hat i$,$\hat j$ and $\hat k$ and take the sum and square root it to get the magnitude of the vector.If you are interested, you can check the derivation of the distance formula in 3D geometry.It looks similar....link:https://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/Vectors/vect.h9.gif and http://math.tutorvista.com/calculus/distance-formula-in-3d.html

Comment: *Facepalm* Yes, I get what you are saying. But how does it equal one...what trigonmetric expressions must I employ...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Standard stuff, I should have got this. Thank you :)